# GitLab CI - Keep last pipeline status

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

In GitLab CI, is it possible to keep the last pipeline status when no jobs are queued upon a push? I have a `changes` rule setup like this in my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
changes: 
  - Assets/*
  - Packages/*
  - ProjectSettings/*
  - .gitlab-ci.yml
```

which applies to all jobs in the pipeline (these are build jobs for Unity, though irrelevant). NOTE: I only wanted to run a build job if there are any actual files changes that would require a rebuild. changes to `README.md` and `CONTRIBUTING.md` are **not** changes that require a rebuild so this is why I have such a rule.

Problem is I require successful pipeline to merge branches and when I try to merge a branch that modified `README.md` there obviously is no pipeline. [image: Checking pipeline status stuck]

Is there a way to just "reuse" the result of a previous pipeline or to have a "dummy" job that succeeds instantly upon any push, so as to be able to merge this branch without requiring an expensive rebuild of the whole project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in your last paragraph, the only way to work around this would be to inject a dummy job that always succeed; something like `echo "hello world"` in the script.

However, depending on how long your tests run, your best bet may be to just have your tests run every time regardless of changes. Any sort of partial pipeline run using the `changes` keyword leaves you open to merging changes that break your pipeline. It essentially tightly couples your logic in your pipeline to the component structure of your code, which isn't always a good thing since one of the points of your pipeline is to catch those kinds of cross-component breakages.